# Add custom attribute to user created in AWS Cognito console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I have an app with AWS Cognito auth implemented using Amplify. I do not want users to be able to sign up, instead the admin will sign up users via the AWS Cognito user pool console, by creating a new user.

I have created a custom attribute for users for a AWS Cognito userpool. I want to assign a value to that attribute for a user either when creating the user or after the user is created.

I cannot see how to fill in any values for attributes for a user when creating a user in the AWS Coginto user pool console.

When opening a created user in the console, I do not see how to add values for  attributes for that user.

I have probably missed something in the Docs, but can someone tell me how to add values for attributes (including custom ones) for a user created in the AWS Cognito userpool console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple solution.
Cognito console doesn't allow to input custom attributes or required any attributes by admin. This is norm because the user's info should be filled by himself.

So This is the workflow how this invitation auth flow would work in Cognito:

- The admin creates new user in the console by inputting username, temp password only(He can chooses whether to send a verification email or not and auto-verified phone number or email upon creating)
- Cognito will send the invitation email to the user with verification code or link `codeParameter` (If you would use custom message Lambda trigger trigger for this use case, you can customize the email message and put the username and temporary password along together).
  At this point, you should include URL to redirect the user to your app's update password page.
- In this update page, you should let him to input any required attributes himself and change password to complete the signup (In Cognito console, you should configure any attributes you need to get upon signup as required).

Here is the helpful link for you to review in order to understand how to complete the signup with Cognito by Amplify Lib:
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js#complete-new-password

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.  Unfortunately I want the admin to add the custom attributes, the users wouldn't be involved in adding any attributes they could just change their password.  I suppose I can use DynamoDB to hold data about the user and query that in a post authentication hook to add that data to the claims in the token for the user (?)  so that the app will be aware of the custom attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I think it will also work. instead you should never set those attributes as required since if you do it, it will be required the client user to set them on completion signup.